# How to check the result of PrintUIEntry call

Tags: winapi, printing

I'd like to use `PrintUIEntryW` (of `printui.dll` ) to install a printer driver on Windows system. My code looks like following (pseudo).

```
m = LoadLibrary(L"printui.dll");
printuientry = GetProcAddress(m, "PrintUIEntryW");
// set arg_string
printuientry(NULL, m, arg_string, SW_SHOW);
```

Could I check the return value of the function or something like `GetLastError()` to check if the desired call is successful? There seems no msdn entry for this function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason for avoiding [`AddPrinter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: To use AddPrinterDriver, had to parse .inf file. Guess it's tedious and more error-prone. Isn't it?

Comment: There's always [`UploadPrinterDriverPackage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`InstallPrinterDriverFromPackage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanx. I'll take a look at the functions you suggested. However, I might need to run it on XP systems also.

Answer (score 0):

`PrintUIEntry` is documented here:

[Rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057.aspx)

`rundll32` is documented is here:

[INFO: Windows Rundll and Rundll32 Interface](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164787)

Most importantly:

> In your DLL, write the  function with the following prototype:
>
> 16-bit DLL:
>
> ```
> void FAR PASCAL __loads EntryPoint(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
> ```
>
> 32-bit DLL:
>
> ```
> void CALLBACK EntryPoint(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> On Windows NT, Windows 2000, and Windows XP the behavior of Rundll32.exe is slightly different, in order to accommodate UNICODE command lines.
>
> Windows NT first attempts to GetProcAddress for W. If this entry point is found, then the prototype is assumed to be:
>
> ```
> void CALLBACK EntryPointW(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPWSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
> ```
>
> This is the same as the ANSI EntryPoint, except that the lpszCmdLine parameter is now a UNICODE string.

As you can see, functions designed to be used with `rundll32` **do not have a return value**.  And `PrintUIEntry` is not documented as using `SetLastError()` for error reporting.  So, in this case, you cannot do any kind of error handling.  You will have to use a different API that reports errors.