# How to fix PrintUIEntry returns error code 2

Tags: c, winapi, dll

I have some problem. Here is my code:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *pPrintUIEntry)(HWND, HMODULE, wchar_t *, DWORD);

printuiDll = LoadLibrary("printui.dll");

if (printuiDll == NULL)
{
  printf("Error LoadLibrary %d.\n", GetLastError());

  return -1;
}

PrintUIEntry = (pPrintUIEntry) GetProcAddress(printuiDll, "PrintUIEntryW");

if (PrintUIEntry == NULL)
{
  printf("Error GetProcAddress %d.\n", GetLastError());

  return -1;
}
//cmd is /ia /m "Printer" /f "C:\Program Files x86)\\drivers\Printer\Printer.inf

if (PrintUIEntry(GetDesktopWindow(), printuiDll, cmd, SW_SHOW))
{
  printf("Error PrintUIEntry %d.\n", GetLastError());

  return -1;
}
```

Sorry I can't copy the code its my university work. The problem I have is that `PrintUIEntry` returns 0 and it gives me error withe code `2`. I've tried to google little bit about this function but I could found much. Hope you can help. thanks.

I've checked and file exists.

Comment: From a command prompt, type `rundll32.exe printui.dll PrintUIEntry`, and look at the additional information it's expecting. What gives you the impression you can call it directly with none of those details? Where do you find the documentation for the parameters you're passing to it? And why on Earth would you expect it to be looking for the HMODULE of the DLL it's already been loaded from as one of those parameters?

Comment: What are you expecting us to tell you? Error is file not found. But then you knew that because you looked it up. Is that relevant? Maybe. What is value of cmd? Only you know.

Comment: The process is launched remotly I can't check the value of cmd, and sorry I'll add more details

Comment: So in other words you have no idea what your code does and you want somebody to explain its behaviour.

Comment: No, I want to know why I get the error code `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation:

[INFO: Windows Rundll and Rundll32 Interface](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164787)

[Rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057.aspx)

You would see that your declaration of the `PrintUIEntryW` function pointer is wrong.  Most importantly, functions that are designed to be called by `rundll32` **do not have a return value**, and `PrintUIEntry` is not documented as using `SetLastError()` for error reporting.

So you cannot do any kind of error checking in this situation.

1. You are checking for a non-existent `BOOL` value, which means you are checking for whatever *random value* happens to be stored in the `EAX` cpu register when `PrintUIEntryW` exits.  `PrintUIEntryW` has no return value that you can check.
2. You are calling `GetLastError()` to retrieve the last error code that was set by `SetLastError()`.  That may or may not be related to any `PrintUIEntryW` errors, since it not documented behavior.  For instance, `PrintUIEntryW` could be using other APIs internally, which might use `SetLastError()`/`GetLastError()` for their own error reporting, and would be handled by `PrintUIEntryW` internally.  Such errors should not be interpreted by any code that is calling `PrintUIEntryW`, since the code has no context in which to interpret the errors.

In this case, this question becomes a duplicate of [How to check the result of PrintUIEntry call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505112/).

Since you are trying to install a printer, consider using [`AddPrinter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183343.aspx) or [`InstallPrinterDriverFromPackage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144997.aspx) instead.

Comment: One more question please I have code like this `Log() << "Before -> " << GetLastError() << ".\n";

  PrintUIEntry(GetDesktopWindow(), printuiDll, cmd, SW_SHOW);

  Log() << "After -> " << GetLastError() << ".\n";`

and it returns `after -> 2`

Comment: I addressed that in my answer.